# How to poll status of a system process with XHR.poll in Luci openwrt?

Tags: javascript, lua, openwrt, luci

I am running a process . Now i can able to see the status of a process with `pidof "process" >> /dev/null;echo $?` . This will return 0 or another values .

In `Luci` can i do `XHR.poll` to get the status of process with each 5 second like

```
XHR.poll(5, '<%=luci.sys.exe("pidof "process" >> /dev/null;echo $?")%>', null,
        function(x, information)
        {
            //do something

        }
```

Is this correct ? if not , can i get any samples for doing polling a status of a process in luci/lua ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved . We can poll the XHR request by adding

```
XHR.poll(5, '<%=REQUEST_URI%>', {query:1},
function(x, rv){
  //add response actions here
 }
);
```

and with `query : 1` you can perform the `luci.sys.exe` process by adding `luci.http.formvalue("status") == "1"` in a if loop of lua code